# How to add date at name of file txt

Tags: bash

I am using curl to get an information of eurobasket2017 this works correct but I launch this curl everyday with a cron.

```
curl -o dailyGameCode http://live.fibaeurope.com/www/KeyFacts.ashx?acc=0&lng=en&full=1
```

How can I pass the following format to a name of the file ?

```
date +%d-%m-%y
```

Regards !

Answer (score 3):

You can do shell substitution to get the date and then append it to the file name.

**Example**

```
$ today=$(date +%d-%m-%y)
$ curl -o "dailyGameCode-$today" http://live.fibaeurope.com/www/KeyFacts.ashx?acc=0&lng=en&full=1
$ ls
dailyGameCode-01-09-17
```

Comment: Nice , it is a good idea .. can you help to me to download this file as XML ?

Comment: @jc1992 The content type of the response is xml. You can just save it the file and use it. (with extension if you want them to be)